# AC Replacement Proposal

Tags: hvac, replacement

Can someone please help to review if the following AC replacement proposal makes sense and sounds reasonable?

Installation
Remove and disposal of existing equipment, disassemble systems so they can be brought to the roof, reassemble system, rinse copper lines with RX11-flush to remove debris, install new 2 ton 14 SEER Trane rooftop unit (Model 4ycc4024a1060a), rewire high and low voltage wires, a vacuum system to eliminate air and moisture, charge the new system with R410A Freon, check the thermostat for proper communication with the unit, run and test system to ensure proper operation.
Warranty
10 yr parts and compressor warranty; 4 yr labor warranty.

They charge $10K for this job. I live in a walk-up building without an elevator and a small hatch to the roof. So, the AC unit needs to be brought to the roof either by crane or disassembling and reassembling parts. A lot of the AC companies don't even want to do this business. It is also hard to operate a crane due to the many cable lines in my area.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Is a RTU your only option here? I'd think that a minisplit would be easier to maneuver into position, given your relatively small tonnage requirements...also, what's your winter outdoor design temperature (99% temperature)?

Comment: RTU is the only option, unfortunately. I am at the east coast so the average low temp is between 21-34F, but it can be as low as 15F sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: Minisplit with the outer part on the roof could do that load. And blow the doors off that lousy 14 SEER rating. And provide heat all winter at an attractive COP, if that would be helpful or desirable. Minisplits with "ductable" inside parts exist if that's the issue. Shop harder, it might be worth it. I got two 1-tons completely installed for less than that, and it would have been nearly half the price if I could have done it with one two-ton (the differences in price were small between tonnage ratings) but I did not opt to see if I could install ducts and go that way and come out ahead.

Comment: Don't know what size your hatch is, but the units were easily hand-carried without disassembly.

Comment: Yeah really... a huge bulky air conditioner that only cools, is yesterday's news on the market. Mini-splits are much smaller form-factor because they're designed to be hand carried to difficult places.   And their heating function can work in quite cold ambient temps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My place is small and I guess that's the biggest problem.  will shop around and see what's the best option.